# Using Kotlin contracts to cast type inside Iterable function predicate

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-contracts

I have this sealed class `PictureEvent`:

```
sealed class PictureEvent {

    data class PictureCreated(val pictureId: String, val url: String) : PictureEvent()

    //more classes extending PictureEvent

}
```

Now, from a list of `PictureEvent`s, I want to get the first `PictureCreated`:

```
fun doSomething(events: List<PictureEvent>) {

  val creationEvent = events.first { isCreationEvent(it) } as PictureEvent.PictureCreated

  //do stuff with the creationEvent

}

private fun isCreationEvent(event: PictureEvent) : Boolean {
  return event is PictureEvent.PictureCreated
}
```

It works fine. As you see, I'm casting the event to `PictureCreated` (using `as` keyword), since `first` method, returns a `PictureEvent`. I wonder if it's possible to avoid this casting by using Kotlin contracts.

I have tried this:

```
private fun isCreationEvent(event: PictureEvent) : Boolean {
  contract {
    returns(true) implies (event is PictureEvent.PictureCreated)
  }
  return event is PictureEvent.PictureCreated
}
```

But it doesn't work; `first` method keep returning a `PictureEvent`, instead of `PictureCreated`. Is it possible to do this currently?

Comment: The code should work as expected, can you show how did you called the `isCreationEvent()`?

Comment: You can see it in the question. `events.first { isCreationEvent(it) }`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The contract works fine, however if you take a look at the `first` method signature, you should be able to understand what is happening and why the found object isn't autocast:

```
public inline fun <T> Iterable<T>.first(predicate: (T) -> Boolean): T
```

The return type of the `first` method is just the same as that defined for all elements in the `Iterable` instance, `PictureEvent` in your case, and no autocasting inside the predicate can unfortunately change that.

---

Instead of contracts, for example, you can filter your list by the desired class type first, and then take the first element:

```
val creationEvent = events
    .filterIsInstance(PictureEvent.PictureCreated::class.java)
    .first()
```

or create your own extension similar to `first`:

```
inline fun <reified R> Iterable<*>.firstOfInstance(): R {
    val first = first { it is R }
    return first as R
}

// or wrapping filterIsInstance
inline fun <reified R> Iterable<*>.firstOfInstance(): R {
    return filterIsInstance(R::class.java).first()
}

val creationEvent = events.firstOfInstance<PictureEvent.PictureCreated>()
```

Comment: I didn't know filterIsInstance method. It's quite clean. Thank you!